# Convert a character string of hexadecimal digits into bigint?

Tags: mysql, sql, type-conversion, overflow, bigint

I have a table like this:

```
create table valid_device (
  id char(8) not null default '' comment 'id',
  begin char(24) not null comment 'device id that is valid begin',
  end char(24) comment 'device id that is valid end',
  primary key (id)
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8mb4 comment='valid device';
```

[image]

if I wrote:
[image]

It's OK.
but if I wrote:
[image]
That's not what I want.

if I use CONV('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 16, 10), it will cause an bigint overflow?
what should i do?
thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

> if I use CONV('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 16, 10), it will cause an bigint overflow?

Of course.

> what should i do?

If you need to check does a value is between `begin` and `end` then you may use string compare where all values are normalized to the same length.

For the value matched `CHAR(24)` use `LPAD(TRIM(value), @length, '0')` where integer `@length` is 24 or more.